# 500 Internal error with JQuery data submission

Tags: jquery

I'm sending values from a form to the DB using jQuery on my server and it's working fine.

Now I moved the website to another server and it doesn't work anymore.

When I hit the "send" button, I get an alert with "[object Object]", and if I inspect I see :

```
POST [...truncated url...]/contact_conveyor.php?timestamp=607 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here's my code :

```
var oDate = new Date();
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});

$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" });

$.ajax({    
  url: 'contact_conveyor.php?timestamp='+oDate.getMilliseconds(),
  data: {language:language,email:email,fullName:fullName,message:message},
  dataType: 'html',
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  success : function(text){
    var output = '<div class="formulaire reponse">'+text+"</div>";
    $(".formulaire").replaceWith(output);
  },
  error : function(text){
      alert(text);
  }
});
```

I checked the contact_conveyor.php permissions and they're set to 777 +x.  What shall I try ?  It was working fine on the other server ! :o)

I've removed everything from the PHP file that gets called except an echo statement and I still get the 500 Internal Server Error.

Is there a php.ini setting that could cause that ?

Comment: Can you post the code to  contact_conveyor.php?

Comment: how long does it take to execute. maybe it is timing out? or maybe access is denied..

Comment: I removed everything in my PHP file and simply kept an echo statement.  I should be at least getting that echo statement through my jQuery "success" function, but I still get the "error" function throwing out an "object [object]" error and I see the 500 internal error when I inspect with Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not jQuery related.

Your file ***contact_conveyor.php*** is producing an error when executed.

Since you've moved to a different server, check that php file for server paths and/or
other server related configuration variables.

Comment: I wonder what can cause this in my PHP file.  And what kink of server related configuration could cause this ?  I'm simply loading a 10 line PHP asynchronously with a MySQL insert ...

Comment: It was a file permission issue. I don't know the numbers for the permissions but I had to set the file permission to :

owner: read/write group: read others: read exec: no

Thanks for your help folks !

Answer (score 0):

First, use [firebugs](http://getfirebug.com/) [**net tab**](http://getfirebug.com/network) to see exactly what is being sent, where it is being sent to and what the exact response is.  Then look at your PHP to figure out why its generating that response for the given input.

Comment: Hi !
I just have an echo "Hello World" and it's still shows an error.  I see the data is being sent correctly but it shouldn't matter since my PHP script is supposed to output the echo statement and that's all.  It's very weird, I'm trying to see if there's php.ini setting that could cause PHP file not to be accessed directly.  I read that the permissions must not be set to 777 so I put it to 775 and still to no avail...